# runtime error is thrown in the thread "main"

Tags: exception, java-8, try-catch, program-entry-point

I cannot catch the exception, instead a runtime error is thrown in the main method.

Any idea?

code below:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
        String[] myArray;

        try{
            while(true){
                myList.add("My String");
            }
        }catch(RuntimeException re){
            System.out.println("Caught a RuntimeException");
        }catch(Exception re){
            System.out.println("Caught a Exception");
        }
        System.out.println("Ready to use");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It will throw OutOfMemoryError which do not extend Exception. So you can not catch it by Exception.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
    try{
        while(true){
            myList.add("My String");
        }
    }catch(RuntimeException re){
        System.out.println("Caught a RuntimeException");
    }catch(Exception re){
        System.out.println("Caught a Exception");
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e){
        System.out.println("Out of memory");
    }
    System.out.println("Ready to use");
}
```